# What is the name of this style? (Karate maybe?)

Tags: technique, sparring, grading, identification

I've seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZhpiAIfhts) around a fair bit, 
but I can't find much background about who / what organization / style it is?

Comment: That's a godan grading! Words fail me... Whatever style it is, stay as far away from it as you can!

Comment: Even though the style is rather questionable, I don't think we should revert to name-calling here. Can you please change the  question's tag?

Comment: the tag is how its tagged on the internet

Comment: @KeithNicholas - The internet has different standards than most SE sites.

Comment: I am in Michael Dealys class. There is no contact and we do Tae Kwon Do. I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The video is from the [World Martial Arts Association](http://wmaa.com) which was setup by Michael T. Dealy in the early 1990s, Mike Dealy [trained under Grandmaster Duk Sung Son](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duk_Sung_Son). The style is [Chung Do Kwan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chung_Do_Kwan), a form of Tae Kwon Do with light or no-contact.

The WMAA has [a video channel on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/THEWMAAChannel), but about a year ago all video's were removed, probably because of the criticism they received. The WMAA is often ridiculed on the Internet as being a McDojo/McDojang
(for example see [here](http://www.cagepotato.com/awful-video-of-the-day-the-mcdojo-5th-degree-black-belt-test/), [here](http://www.bullshido.net/forums/archive/index.php/t-95703.html) and [here](http://www.martialartsplanet.com/forums/showthread.php?t=116571))

More information:

- http://wmaa.com/about/
- http://www.oneworldtaekwondo.com/html/history.html